# Does Android MediaCodec uses hardware codec?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, stagefright

I am confused with what codec is used by Android `MediaCodec` ?

From the below link:

```
https://vec.io/tags/ffmpeg
```

I could sense that, `MediaCodec` is used for hardware encoding.

But then, when I look at

"New Low-Level Media APIs in Android" presentation by Dave Burke, from Google Summit 2012, `MediaCodec` is a framework providing an architecture to introduce new codec by means of `OMX IL` in the HAL Layer. [ Please correct me if i am wrong ? ] that means, it can be either hardware codec, or software codec.

How can I assure that if hardware codec is used?

Comment: Both are available.  Which is used depends on the codec in question and your platform.  For example, hardware AVC codecs are available on all Nexus devices, but the emulator uses a software AVC codec.  Are you asking generally, or did you want a runtime check on a specific instance of MediaCodec?

Comment: @fadden If you have any advice on how to check at runtime if the codec is hardware of software, I'd like to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: @fadden,@ganesh 'is there any runtime checks, or any hints to verify which is used by MediaCodec ? In Samsung devices I usually see logs printing MFC adapter, What does it mean to?